# Use PowerShell developer command prompt to build solution

Tags: powershell, msbuild

How do use the developer powershell command prompt Launch-VsDevShell.ps1 in powershell script to compile solution ?

I want to compile inside the environment of the developer console
when runing this script i get all environment variable accessible

when i launch the Launch-VsDevShell.ps1 from script i dont have see option to add parameters to start msbuild after the execution of the Launch-VsDevShell.ps1 with given parameters.

i wish to strta the Launch-VsDevShell.ps1 with argumets .
somthing like this

& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\Tools\Launch-VsDevShell.ps1" -arglist

when using direct msbuild.exe i use the follwoing code

```
        $arglist = "$workfolder\build\$sln /m  /nr:false /bl:$workfolder\Logs\binarylog_$date_$sln.binlog /nologo  /flp:errorsonly;LogFile=$msbuildlogErr"
        
        $resbuild = Start-Process $msbuild -ArgumentList $arglist -PassThru
```

i couldn't find any example

Comment: `Launch-VsDevShell.ps1` doesn't launch Visual Studio and can't be used to build a solution. The `Launch-VsDevShell.ps1` PowerShell script launches and configures a PowerShell session for supporting command line Visual Studio development tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Source the file, which will set all environment variables, then compile using msbuild as usual:

```
. "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\Tools\Launch-VsDevShell.ps1" 
msbuild /path/to/solution.sln
```